# jQuery finding data from div tag

Tags: jquery

Using bootstrap theme to create a dropdown button with menu, I'm trying to get the data-pay_for_month in the div tag when I click "Paid Today".

HTML

```
<div data-pay_for_month="1375315200" class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
    Set
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
    <li><a class="paid-today">Paid today</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var $this = $(this);
alert($this.closest("div").find('.btn-group').data('pay_for_month'));
```

Output is still undefined. What is wrong? Did it find the wrong closest div?

Comment: I assume `.closest("div")` contains the `.btn-group` itself (because it's the closest `div`). `.find` will only search for *descendants* of the selected elements and an element cannot be a descendant of itself. Try `$this.closest("div").data('pay_for_month')`.

Comment: Can you show us more of your js code, we need to see the whole function to know what $(this) is.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` looks for descendants of an element but in your case the closest div is itself the `.btn-group`, so you can just filter `closest()` to make sure you get the div with the class you need

```
$('.paid-today').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('div.btn-group').data('pay_for_month'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.find('.paid-today').on('click', function() { alert($(this).parents('.btn-group').data('pay_for_month')) })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do...

```
$('.paid-today').click(function(){

alert($(this).closest("div").data('pay_for_month'));

});
```